# I created the following code, the code execute too slow, it does not show the full out put of the stream function, how I should optimize the code?

Tags: plotting

```
f[x_, y_] := ((-((1 - ϕ Sin[δ] + ϵ ϕ Cos[k δ] Sin[δ]) + 
                  (1 + ϕ Sin[x] + ϵ ϕ Cos[k x] Sin[x] + 
                   ϕ Sin[x - δ] - ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x -])))/
              (1 + ϕ Sin[x] + ϵ ϕ Cos[k x] Sin[x] + 
               ϕ Sin[x - δ] - ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x - δ])^3) 
              (2 (y^3 - (-ϕ Sin[x - δ] + ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x - δ])^3) - 
              3 (1 + ϕ Sin[x] + ϵ ϕ Cos[k x] Sin[x] - ϕ Sin[x - δ] + 
              ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x - δ]) (y^2 - (-ϕ Sin[x - δ] + 
              ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x - δ])^2) + 6 (1 + ϕ Sin[x] +
              ϵ ϕ Cos[k x] Sin[x]) (-ϕ Sin[x - δ] + 
              ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x - δ]) 
            (y - (-ϕ Sin[x - δ] + ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x - δ]))) - 
             (y - (-ϕ Sin[x - δ] + ϵ ϕ Cos[k (x - δ)] Sin[x - δ]));
δ = Pi/3; ϵ = 0.1; ϕ = 0.2; k = 0.5; 
p2 = ContourPlot[
  f[x, y] == Range[-5, 2, 0.1], {x, 0, 13}, {y, 0, 1.3}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black(*,Thin*)], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 13}, {0, 1.3}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "v(x)"}(*,
  PerformanceGoal\[Rule]"Speed"*)] (*plot seven streamlines*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `DensityPlot` instead of `ContourPlot`? (`ContourPlot` basically has to repeat the same work once for each contour line, while `DensityPlot` only evaluates each point once, then compares the value at each point with the values in the `Mesh` array)

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 13}, {y, 0, 1.3}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
  Mesh -> {Range[-5., 2, 0.1]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Black, Thin, Opacity[0.5]}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

(BTW there's a syntax error in your code `Sin[x -]`. I had to make a guess what was missing here.)